# Keeping Raspberry Pi OS and other apps automatically up to date

Tags: update

I currently keep everything up to date by using the following commands via CLI:

`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt full-upgrade`

I'd like to do this daily, automatically.

I know in the past you were able to install [Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) on Raspbian to keep the OS and other apps up to date.

Can this still be used with the newer [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

You can also use the command:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

And follow these steps from here:  [Pimpmylife](https://pimylifeup.com/unattended-upgrades-debian-ubuntu/)